# Auto leveling with Marlin and RAMPS 1.4 does not work

Tags: marlin, bed-leveling

I configured Marlin 1.1.3 for auto-leveling with a fix mounted sensor connected to the Z end-stop pin.

I have the following settings in my config:

```
#define X_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER 25  
#define Y_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER 20  
#define Z_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER 0   // Z offset: -below +above  [the nozzle]

#define Z_CLEARANCE_DEPLOY_PROBE   10 // Z Clearance for Deploy/Stow
#define Z_CLEARANCE_BETWEEN_PROBES  5 // Z Clearance between probe points

#define AUTO_BED_LEVELING_BILINEAR

#define GRID_MAX_POINTS_X 7
#define GRID_MAX_POINTS_Y GRID_MAX_POINTS_X

// The Z probe minimum outer margin (to validate G29 parameters).
#define MIN_PROBE_EDGE 10

// Set the boundaries for probing (where the probe can reach).
#define LEFT_PROBE_BED_POSITION 25
#define RIGHT_PROBE_BED_POSITION 150
#define FRONT_PROBE_BED_POSITION 30
#define BACK_PROBE_BED_POSITION 180
```

I enter `M111 S38` to enable LEVELING+INFO+ERROR debugging.
Then I enter `G28` to home all axes and then enter `G29` to start auto-leveling.

The auto-leveling starts successfully and after finishing I see the scan grid in console:

```
12:41:35.983 : Bilinear Leveling Grid:
12:41:35.983 : 0      1      2      3      4      5      6
12:41:35.983 : 0 -3.127 -3.405 -3.405 -3.292 -3.595 -3.487 -3.537
12:41:35.983 : 1 -3.110 -3.367 -3.337 -3.220 -3.470 -3.350 -3.365
12:41:35.983 : 2 -3.138 -3.367 -3.330 -3.215 -3.442 -3.345 -3.385
12:41:35.984 : 3 -3.013 -3.225 -3.182 -3.047 -3.225 -3.132 -3.150
12:41:35.984 : 4 -2.970 -3.165 -3.097 -2.972 -3.160 -3.045 -3.065
12:41:35.984 : 5 -2.875 -3.075 -3.005 -2.847 -2.990 -2.872 -2.875
12:41:35.984 : 6 -2.680 -2.845 -2.755 -2.615 -2.753 -2.617 -2.622
12:41:35.985 : G29 uncorrected Z:10.00
12:41:35.985 : corrected Z:12.85
12:41:35.985 : <<< gcode_G29
12:41:35.985 : X:120.00 Y:160.00 Z:12.85 E:0.00 Count X:9600 Y:12800 Z:4000
12:41:35.985 : current_position=(120.00, 160.00, 12.85) : sync_plan_position
```

So the auto-leveling scanning seems to be successful.

Here is a visual of the leveling grid (but upside down to make it easier to view):

[image: Inverted visual of the leveling grid]

Naturally I **DO NOT** enter `G28` after the scanning.

I enter `G0 Z1` to down nozzle almost to table. But when I enter for example `G0 X25 Y30` and look at level and then I enter `G0 X150 Y150` I see the big difference between nozzle levels relatively to table. So it seems that height compensation does not work. I expect that Z axis would lift up or down depending on auto-leveling results but Z motor do not work when I move X/Y.

By the way I tried 3 point autoleveling. It was pretty rough but Z axis corrected it's level when I moved axes using `G0` commands.
And to avoid questions "why my table is inclined so much?" I deliberately inclined the table to be sure that auto leveling works. By the way, I tried different `Z_PROBE_OFFSET_FROM_EXTRUDER` so the current 0 setting is not actual but situation is the same with any value of this option.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I plotted your leveling grid and the axis that is opposite your incline is going up and down quite a bit.  Could your table be wobbling/rocking and this is throwing off the auto-level?

Comment: hmm, i didn' thought abot it, will check

Comment: btw what software did you use to visualize the mesh?

Comment: I created the visualization using Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bed leveling is disabled by default. So the mesh was scanned but is not apllied after G29 command. To apply the mesh we need to enable bed leveling using

```
M420 S1
```

command

Answer (score 3):

In additional to Sergey's answer `M420 S1` should be put into custom start G-code. By default Marlin disables autobed after `G28` unless specifically configured otherwise

```
/**
* Normally G28 leaves leveling disabled on completion. Enable
* this option to have G28 restore the prior leveling state.
*/
#define RESTORE_LEVELING_AFTER_G28
```